# Transform Dataframe with Multiple Headers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following excel file with multiple sheet: [Link to World Bank WGI](https://info.worldbank.org/governance/wgi/Home/downLoadFile?fileName=wgidataset.xlsx).
I am trying to change the format of the files as follows, 
**From:**
[Original df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EtIf.png)
The original dataframe has a row with years (index=12) above the row with indicator names (index=13). Each country has its own row (col=0).
**To:**
[Output df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ja9H.png)
In the output dataframe, I want to add a column with the years from index=12. Then, repeat the country for each year and stack the data based on the year and country as order remains the same. 
If someone's solution has all the sheets in one big dataframe, that is helpful as well. I will be combining them all in the end. Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to unstack this line to a column,

```
def tgrp(df):
    df = df.drop('Year', axis=1)
    return df.reset_index(drop=True).T

df2.groupby('Year').apply(tgrp).unstack()
```

Comment: 'Year' doesn't have a column at the moment. It needs to be converted from a row to a column stacked.

Comment: You can try transpose or pivot table to reshape dataframes as you need.